# Find all the dates and time in a string using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, date, search, time

I have richtextbox with many lines and each line has 2 or less dates and times for example:

```
08/10/2015 09:16:27 | Starting the main loop
08/10/2015 09:19:58 | Weight 
08/10/2015 10:01:28 | 08/10/2015 10:01:28 | Exception occurred: Timed out.
08/10/2015 11:13:02 | triggered
08/10/2015 11:14:08 | 08/10/2015 11:14:57 | Exception occurred: Timed out.
```

What I want to do is to be able extract the date and time from each line and store them into two separate arrays, one for date and one for time.

What I have managed to do is to find the total number of dates in a string  using the below code.

```
Dim totalDates As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches("string to search here", "[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]{4}")
MessageBox.Show(totalDates.Count)
```

Is there a way to obtain the actually dates and time from the string?

Thank You

Comment: You could loop through each line and split on the `|`. Then you can use DateTime.TryParse to get the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same format every time, you can use something like this:

```
For Each item As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
    Dim split() = item.Split({" | "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    split = split.Take(split.Length - 1).ToArray()
    For Each item2 As String In split
        ' Do your work here. Maybe you want to parse the dates?
        Dim date1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(item2)
        ' Do something with your Date here...
    Next
Next
```

Here's a demo at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wuFFg6).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably extract the dates with regex but I only recommend regex as a last resort. (Also avoided in the first answer.) My code is old style VB, the first post is the more modern .Net style.

Here is my pass:

```
    Dim s As String = "08/10/2015 09:16:27 | Starting the main loop" & vbCrLf
    s &= " 08/10/2015 09:19:58 | Weight " & vbCrLf
    s &= " 08/10/2015 10:01:28 | 08/10/2015 10:01:28 | Exception occurred: Timed out." & vbCrLf
    s &= " 08/10/2015 11:13:02 | triggered" & vbCrLf
    s &= " 08/10/2015 11:14:08 | 08/10/2015 11:14:57 | Exception occurred: Timed out." & vbCrLf

    TextBox1.Text = s & vbNewLine

    Dim a() As String = s.Split({vbCr, vbLf, "|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each s In a
        If IsDate(s) Then
            TextBox1.AppendText(CDate(s).ToShortDateString & "  :::  " & CDate(s).ToShortTimeString & vbNewLine)
        End If
    Next
```

You can also process line by line using the .Lines() property of the test control.

Comment: Sorry to say but it won't work.. just for a trivial error.. I'll give you some time to find it yourself.